# angular-filter nested groupby

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angular-filters

Having problems with groupBy filter of [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module in a nested array. The 'location' is undefined and 'color' isn't outputting anything. Took this example and modified it from someone else's code.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('app',['angular.filter']).controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'[
            {location: 'texas',
            color: 'blue'}]},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'[
            {location: 'texas',
            color: 'red'}]},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'[
            {location: 'kansas',
            color: 'purple'}]},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'[
            {location: 'kansas',
            color: 'green'}]},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'[
            {location: 'kansas',
            color: 'orange'}]}
];
});
</script>

<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainController"> 

<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team.location'">
Group name: {{ key }}
<li ng-repeat="player in value">
player: {{ player.name }}  <br/>
favorite color: {{ player.color }} 
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your data structure doesn't correspond to your code logic. This works fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('app',['angular.filter']).controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
            $scope.players = [
              {name: 'Gene',
                team: {location: 'texas',
                      color: 'blue'}
              },
              {name: 'George', team: {location: 'texas',
                        color: 'red'}},
              {name: 'Steve', team: 
                        {location: 'kansas',
                        color: 'purple'}},
              {name: 'Paula', team: 
                        {location: 'kansas',
                        color: 'green'}},
              {name: 'Scruath', team:
                        {location: 'kansas',
                        color: 'orange'}}
            ];
            });
        </script>

        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
            <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team.location'">
                Group name: {{ key }}
                <li ng-repeat="player in value">
                player: {{ player.name }}  <br/>
                favorite color: {{ player.color }} 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```