# GroupBy filter is not working in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have created a table in angularjs. Now I am trying to group the table rows based on a column value whose title is "source".

For that, I am using groupBy filter. It is not giving any error. But it is displaying empty rows now. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Below is my code:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Metric</th>
           <th>Source</th>
           <th class="value">Value</th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="metric in metrics | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | groupBy:'info.source'>
            <td class="metric">{{metric.name}}</td>
            <td class="source">{{metric.info.source}}</td>
            <td class="value">{{metric.info.value}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

I am pasting a sample of my Json data to get you an idea about my table data:

```
[{
  "name": "kafka.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "kafka.bringo.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "Error",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
}]
```

Comment: I believe with `groupBy:'info.source'` it tries to do `metric["info.source"]` (and not `metric.info.source`), which has the wrong syntax, so you can't group by nested object property

Comment: I think syntax is correct.. See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065933/angular-filter-nested-groupby

Comment: no, you need to extract the key and value first, here is [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lPhc5YRWSIsFvkm4lKp9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the solution of my problem. Correct way to use "groupBy" filter in table is as below:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);
app.controller("SimpleController", function($scope) {
  $scope.metrics =  [{
  "name": "kafka.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "kafka.bringo.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "Error",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "dm.bingo.health",
  "info": {
 "source": "deployment-manager",
 "value": "Error",
 "timestamp": "1459438855068",
 "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "dm.different.health",
  "info": {
 "source": "deployment-manager",
 "value": "Warn",
 "timestamp": "84834883483",
 "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "kadmfka.bringo.health",
  "info": {
 "source": "deployment-manager",
 "value": "Error",
 "timestamp": "1459438855068",
 "causes": ""
}
}];
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.16/angular-filter.js" > </script>
    <style>
 table{
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 table>thead>tr>th, table>tbody>tr>td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>

</head>    
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div>
            <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">      
             <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Metric</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th class="value">Value</th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="metric in metrics | groupBy:'info.source' ">
    <td class="metric">
     <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in metric">
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td class="source">{{metric[0].info.source}}</td>
    <td class="value">
    <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in metric">
     <td>{{item.info.value}}</td>
     </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in metrics | groupBy:'info.source' ">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);
app.controller("SimpleController", function($scope) {
  $scope.metrics =  [{
  "name": "kafka.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
},
{
  "name": "kafka.bringo.health",
  "info": {
    "source": "kafka",
    "value": "Error",
    "timestamp": "1459438855068",
    "causes": ""
  }
}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.16/angular-filter.js" > </script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">      
         <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Metric</th>
           <th>Source</th>
           <th class="value">Value</th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in metrics | groupBy:'info.source' ">
            <td class="metric">{{key}}</td>
            <td class="source">{{key}}</td>
            <td class="value">{{key}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `key` is a group `value` is the data inside each group (arrays), you can continue your code with `<div ng-repeat="metric in value">` and display the data with `{{metric.name}}` as usual